# Domain X has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-browser

Trying to enable cross domain with Ajax Call but still getting "CORS Policy" error, here is my code:

```
  var settings = {
            "url": "https://testmedia/api/authenticate",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "accept": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            },
            "data": JSON.stringify({
                "user_name": "test",
                "password": "test"
            }),
        };

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

[image]

Comment: You probably need a CORS proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure cors but in your backend.

For example in PHP:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token , Authorization');
```